# php content-type image size

Tags: php, image, content-type

I have this code to display users avatars..

```
<?php
include("../core/config.php");

if(isset($_GET['uid'])){
if(is_numeric($_GET['uid'])){
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];
}
else{
    exit();
}

$sql="SELECT avatar FROM users_avatar WHERE user_id = '$uid'";  
$row= getRow($sql);
if(!$row){
    $url = "../usravatars/_default/usravatar_default_m.png";
}
else{
$avatar = $row['avatar'];
$url = "../usravatars/$uid/$avatar";
}   
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
readfile($url);
}
?>
```

Is possible to set a custom size for the image being displayed?

Comment: Do you mean resizing the image on the fly or using HTML to force the image size?

Comment: I mean resize it inside this code.. I would like to have another $_GET variable like `$_GET['size']` and in my url set to 64 or 32 and then resize the image with width and height 64 or 32.. The base image is 128x128px. EDIT: by resizing, i do not mean to create a copy of that image.. Just force it's size like you said, but if possible inside this code.

Comment: @DjRikyx To do that you can use **GD** or **IMagick**

Comment: I solved this by using **GD** with a php class i found. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a sample function to resize the image on the fly. You can use your own specific width/height or fetch from the get variables.

```
function CroppedThumbnail($imgSrc,$thumbnail_width,$thumbnail_height) { //$imgSrc is a FILE - Returns an image resource.
//getting the image dimensions  
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imgSrc);   
$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($thumbnail_width/$thumbnail_height > $ratio_orig) {
   $new_height = $thumbnail_width/$ratio_orig;
   $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
} else {
   $new_width = $thumbnail_height*$ratio_orig;
   $new_height = $thumbnail_height;
}

$x_mid = $new_width/2;  //horizontal middle
$y_mid = $new_height/2; //vertical middle

$process = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height)); 

imagecopyresampled($process, $myImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height); 
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, ($x_mid-($thumbnail_width/2)), ($y_mid-($thumbnail_height/2)), $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height);

imagedestroy($process);
imagedestroy($myImage);
return $thumb;
}

//Create the thumbnail
$newThumb = CroppedThumbnail("DSC01088.jpg",$_GET['width'],$_GET['height']);

// And display the image...
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($newThumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `header("Content-Type: image/jpg"); readfile($url);` you are sending the full image with its original size to the browser and nothing else.

If you want to display a resized version of the same image try something like

```
echo '<img src="' . $url . '" width="desired-width" />';
```

If you want to resize the original image then look at the first example on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: I tried right now, it work if i see the php file directly.. But i use this script as a `background-image` url..